# Почему в словах "деревянный", "оловянный" и "стеклянный" пишутся две буквы Н?

Tags: орфография, история

Понятное дело, что это исключения. Но в чем причина добавления этих слов в список исключений?

Comment: Раз в году эта школьная тема звучит, зайдите в поиск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ранее в этих словах было **два суффикса ЯН и ЬН**: дерев-ян-ьн-ный, олов-ян-ьн-ный.

После падения редуцированных гласных осталось традиционное написание суффикса ЯНН с двумя НН.